# how to do multipart form-data wcf service

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, http-post

How to do a wcf service using multipart form data inputs. I have done a web service which gets the byte[] of an image and save it in a local path and sends the path of the url. I have tested this with the c#windows/web application which is working fine but then client app such as using objective c could not contact the service and send the byte[]. hence i switch over to the wcf service, which i think may do it easily. btw i dont know much about wcf either.. Below is my sample snippet which i employed in my wp7 app.

WebClient webClient = new WebClient();

```
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentType] = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
            var uri = new Uri("http://localhost/snap/service.asmx/getImages");
            StringBuilder postData = new StringBuilder();
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "EventName", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("sample"));
            postData.AppendFormat("&{0}={1}", "EventVenue", HttpUtility.UrlEncode("chennai"));
            webClient.Headers[HttpRequestHeader.ContentLength] = postData.Length.ToString();
            webClient.UploadStringCompleted += new UploadStringCompletedEventHandler(webClient_UploadStringCompleted);
            webClient.UploadStringAsync(uri, "POST", postData.ToString());
```

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Not sure you may call WCF from IOS anyway... There is a huge implementation over simple XML-HTTP... Are you planning to use Xamarin ?

Comment: how to send the byte[] in objective c to a web service?